# DataGridView - Parent to Child Database Relation - Updating child DataGridView data

Tags: c#, datagridview, parent-child, relationship

Would someone kindly assist me with the following?  I have two DataGridView objects that each display a DataTable, where the two datatables are related with the following code:

```
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
DataTable ParentList = ListToDataTable(_listOfAllAlbumObjects);
DataTable ChildList = ListToDataTable(_listOfAllTrackObjects);
dSet.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[]{ParentList, ChildList});
DataColumn parentRelationColumn = ParentList.Columns["AlbumId"];
DataColumn childRelationColumn = ChildList.Columns["AlbumId"];
dSet.Relations.Add("ParentToChild", parentRelationColumn, childRelationColumn);
ParentDataGridView.DataSource = dSet;
ParentDataGridView.DataMember = "ParentList";
ChildDataGridView.DataSource = ???;
ChildDataGridView.DataMember = "ParentToChild";
```

Both DataTables are actually List<> converted to DataTables with the following:`

```
    public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>( IList<T> data)
    {
              var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
              var table = new DataTable();
              for (var i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
              {
                  PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                  table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
              }
              var values = new object[props.Count];
              foreach (T item in data)
              {
                  for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) 
                  { values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item); }
                  table.Rows.Add(values);
              }
              return table;
          }
```

Initially it appears that the each DataGridView displays the data appropriately; however the child DataGridView does not update with any change of record in the parent DataGridView.

I see that the tables need to be interconnected through the binding-source; however I don't believe there is a true binding-source here.

Could someone please steer me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an MSDN article showing what you want to do:

[How to: Create a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx)

Here's how this might work for you:

Either through the designer or through code add two BindingSources to your project: parentBindingSource and childBindingSource.  Then try this in place of the code you have.

```
// Associate your BSs with your DGVs.
ParentDataGridView.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
ChildDataGridView.DataSource = childBindingSource;

// (Most of) your code here:
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
DataTable ParentList = ListToDataTable(_listOfAllAlbumObjects);
DataTable ChildList = ListToDataTable(_listOfAllTrackObjects);
dSet.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[]{ParentList, ChildList});
DataColumn parentRelationColumn = ParentList.Columns["AlbumId"];
DataColumn childRelationColumn = ChildList.Columns["AlbumId"];
dSet.Relations.Add("ParentToChild", parentRelationColumn, childRelationColumn);

// Let's name this DT to make clear what we're referencing later on.
ParentList.TableName = "ParentListDT";

// Rather than set the data properties on your DGVs, set them in your BindingSources.
parentBindingSource.DataSource = dSet;
parentBindingSource.DataMember = "ParentListDT";

childBindingSource.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
childBindingSource.DataMember = "ParentToChild";
```

Comment: Jay - Thank you for your response. As you will see however, both of the DataTables are converted List<> (see code added above).  Although I can set the DataSource for the 'parent' database to "dSet" (the DataSet) and the DataMember to the first table, I am not certain how to link the DataSource for the child table to the BindingSource, since a BindingSource is not being used.  Any advice?

Comment: @Bill It shouldn't matter where the DataTables come from, as long as they're correctly related in the DataSet.  You'll need to use BindingSources though to manage the relationship in the DataGridViews (to follow the pattern in the article I linked).  My edit should help.

Comment: Thank you taking the time Jay.  Your suggested revisions worked perfectly and comments made it simple to understand.  Many thanks again!

Comment: This is very old but I was wondering if there was a way to apply this method with EF 4. The parent binding seems to work but the child will not pull the associated data. I was wondering if there was a tweak possible to make it work.

Comment: @Pluc - Sorry, I don't know.  Haven't played with EF yet.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks :) I've just found how. It's almost as simple but you have to wire up 1 event. I'm trying to see if I can use reflection to serve all the binding sources with a single event. This is where I found the info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/12/10/master-details-with-entity-framework-explicit-load.aspx