# Pass List<object> as DataGridView DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, attributes, datagridviewcolumn

I would like to pass a `List<Contact>` to a DataGridView but the `Contact` class includes one more list and it doesnt displayed.

```
this.dgvCsv.DataSource = settings.Contacts;
```

The class

```
public class Contact
    {
        [DisplayName("Név")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Cím")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Irányítószám")]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Város")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        public List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i display all item in the `PhoneNumbers` list as a new column?

Comment: Each item in the list have to be a new column

Comment: Perhaps you can define a new property which return `string` and combine all phones into it. Or you can try to use [parent-child](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6063902/1997232) relation.

Comment: You can't do that I'm afraid. You could combine them into one Property and display them in one column, but you can't create a variable number of columns in your datasource from a list. What do you need to do with the data, display only or edit, too?