# DataGridView with XML - "Merging" child records

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I have a simple Windows Forms app where I'm reading an XML file and displaying it's contents in a DataGridView:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds.ReadXmlSchema(@"MySchema.xsd");
    ds.ReadXml(@"MyXML.xml");                       

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

This loads the parent record just fine. However, I have an *optional* child record (located at `ds.Tables[1]`) that I would like to load alongside the dataGridView - either in it's own grid, or just displayed next to the data in `Tables[0]`.

I've tried a couple different things, including adding a second DataGridView:

`dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];` - this does actually display the data, but there's no indication as to which parent record it actually belongs to.

Merging the records: `ds.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[1]);` - this displays the data as I would like, with blanks where a particular row doesn't contain this information. However, it has the side effect of writing everything to `Tables[0]` when I save the data, which I don't want to happen.

I merely want to display this data side-by-side (mimicking the effect of the `Merge` operation, but continue to write to their respective rows.

I'm currently writing the data using `ds.WriteXml(@"Path@");`.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

The basic layout of the XML file is:

```
<parent>
  <child1 property1="" property2="">
    <optionalchild property1="" property2="" />
  </child1>
  <child2 property1="" property2="" />
  .. etc
</parent>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063902/datagridview-parent-to-child-database-relation-updating-child-datagridview-d

Comment: As an alternative and with a little work, you can get [this Master-Detail](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/835501/Master-Detail-Datagridview) in VB converted to C#. I used [Telerik Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) for the heavy lifting, manually fixed the errors, and had to add my own expand/collapse.png's to the `MasterControl.cs [Design]` `RowHeaderIconList.Images` collection.

Comment: @OhBeWise oh my, that's pretty. I'll have to look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XML Linq to parse xml file like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Element("parent").Elements().Select(x => new
            {
                name = x.Name,
                property1 = x.Attribute("property1").Value,
                property2 = x.Attribute("property2").Value,
                child_property1 = x.Element("optionalchild") == null ? null : x.Element("optionalchild").Attribute("property1").Value,
                child_property2 = x.Element("optionalchild") == null ? null : x.Element("optionalchild").Attribute("property2").Value
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: While this is an option, I'm trying to continue doing it like the above to avoid doing all that (changing the code if I add columns, etc). The way I'm currently loading it, I'm already getting the data relations and child table. Everything I need is there, I just can't get it to display properly. I've recently read that DataGridView apparently doesn't support this, so I'm looking into alternatives.

Comment: The make copy of table :             DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
            dt.Merge(ds.Tables[1]);

Comment: That does seem to alleviate the issue of displaying it in the DataGridView, but how do I then write each table back to its respective place? The issue I had with merging is that it turns the output into `<child1 property1="" property2="" childproperty1="">`. Would you mind updating your answer with this method?

Comment: I'm wonder if using a GroupBy() instead of a Merge() would work.  You can display the results of the GroupBy which will create symbolic links back to the original DataSet. This way when you change the data the original DataSet can be saved in same format.

Comment: barring my ability to find a proper solution to my method, I've decided to accept your answer as it will do exactly what I'm trying to do, even if it isn't quite as "simple". Thanks very much for your help!